# Does infrared light pass through active shutter glass?

Tags: visible-light

The glasses that we use for 3D viewing, do they allow infrared light to pass through them? Infrared rays pass through normal glass right? I need the pupil illuminated through infrared LEDs so I need to whether infrared light can pass through each and every kind of glass.

Comment: if it's a polariser based glasses, then no.. IR rays are blocked by polariser as are visible rays..

Comment: Active Shutter Glass is used for 3D viewing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shutter_3D_system if it is polariser based glass then visible light would also not pass through it and how would a person look through it??

Comment: the projection is based that way...2 cross polarised projectors are used to project different images on screen and the glasses would selectively allow only one of them to pass thru.. I would suggest you to go thru the wiki article..

Comment: From where did you get information that infrared rays are blocked by polarized glasses? Can you give a reference link or something.

Comment: that I assumed from the fact that IR rays are actually non-ionizing EM waves exactly like light and polarizers actually work for any EM waves( non-ionizing). Thus, inferred...Actually if goes down to the working of polarizers, they don't allow a particular orientation of electric field..if you want a link, just search for `IR polarizers` in google.

Comment: if you want to know whether you own polarizer will block IR or not, you can do a little experiment, take a camera(to view IR) and a remote(to generate IR). and do the standard polarizer experiment http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIGnMK4YtlE. P.S. This is actually an engineering solution not very scientific one...